# Need help to understand the confusion that is Golangs package and module system

Tags: go, project, go-modules, goimports

Honestly, Golang's package and module system seems to be the most needlessly complex thing I've ever had to deal with. I don't know if it's just me not understanding, a lack of information on this subject, or just Golang in general.

I've created a Go project that I don't want to publish just yet or upload to GitHub yet. It's not inside the GOPATH that I set up because from what I understand with the introduction of modules you can code your projects outside the GOPATH.
The project layout is like this

```
──── MyProject
     ├─── project
     │    ├─── pkg1
     │    │    └─── foo.go
     │    ├─── pkg2
     │    │    └─── bar.go
     │    └─── go.mod
     └─── test
          └─── test.go
```

In `test.go` I'd hope that I could do something like `import "project/pkg1"` but I can't understand how to get it to work. Even if I move `test.go` inside the project and I type `import "/pkg1"` I get a `Cannot import absolute path` error.

I really don't want to have to code all my go projects inside the `%GOPATH%/src` all the time, it seems silly to have to do that.

Again this is probably just me not understanding. Any help on this, whether it be a link to a tutorial or website, would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code) is a good tutorial on this topic.   You do not need to put your go projects in %GOPATH%/src.  If test.go is versioned with and part of the same project as the other code, then move go.mod up the MyProject directory.

Comment: Changing the import string from "project/pkg1" to "/pkg1" is a mistake. Import strings in Go aren't paths (though they commonly look like paths). Each package has an import string, and that string is what you should use wherever you import it from.

Comment: The module system seems infuriatingly /simple/ to me (ie. non-configurable), but I guess it's all relative ;)

Comment: Units test go in the package that they are testing, also, FWIW.   The tooling expects that.

Comment: Its not complicated. You are just using it in a complete inappropriate way. If you insist on doing it the Python way only you will have to use Python.

Comment: @Volker and that's why I asked this question, to see where I'm going wrong with this. And even though I do prefer Python I'd rather move some projects of mine over to golang for reasons that golang can provide

Comment: @Cerise Limón Thankyou for the tutorial, I'll make sure to check it out. test.go is not part of my library, it's just there to test that my code runs fine. So I think I can keep go.mod where it is right?

Comment: The main unit of everything in Go is the package. Packages are built, installed, tested, veted, distributed, imported. They are selfcontained (e.g. their testcode lifes insided the same FS folder). A Module is nothing more that a set of (selfcontained) packages **versioned** together. Packages versioned together life below their module and their import path begin with the module name. For modules with versions <=1 thats all to know.

Comment: I wonder why "how to write go code" is buried under so many other introductory tutorials. I've been trying to figure out how in the heck to use packages and modules, and this whole time I have not seen that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new with go I recommend using go.mod and a flat project structure. Keep your tests with actual code. Anything suffixed with `_test.go` will not be included.

```
go.mod
foo.go
foo_test.go
bar.go
bar_test.go
```

If this is a library put package name whatever you want.

If this is an executable application set `main` as root package name.